# How java implement the access to the enclosing class from an inner inner class?

Tags: java

I have created an inner class in an inner class :

```
public class EnclosingClass {

    public class InnerClass {
        private EnclosingClass getEnclosing() {
            return EnclosingClass.this;
        }

        public class InnerInnerClass {
            private InnerClass getEnclosing() {
                return InnerClass.this;
            }

            private EnclosingClass getEnclosingOfEnclosing() {
                return EnclosingClass.this;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

I have been surprised that java allows the `InnerInnerClass` to access directly  the `EnclosingClass`. How is this code implemented internally by Java?

The `InnerInnerClass` keeps two pointers (one on the `InnerClass` and the other on the `EnclosingClass`) or the InnerInnerClass access the `EnclosingClass` through the `InnerClass` ?

Comment: With *"How this code is implemented ?"*, you mean how Java internally implements inner classes?

Comment: i think he does mean that.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Comment: @ITroubs that actually has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @m0skit0 yes this is my question. If my question is difficult to understand, feel free to improve it.

Comment: @m0skit0 actually it has. I just forgot to mention that he has to look at the post by jrudolph. He explains how Java handles nonstatic inner classes by showing the generated bytecode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to disassemble the resulting class with javap to see what's going on:

```
private EnclosingClass getEnclosingOfEnclosing();
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: getfield      #1                  // Field this$1:LEnclosingClass$InnerClass;
     4: getfield      #3                  // Field EnclosingClass$InnerClass.this$0:LEnclosingClass;
     7: areturn
```

So first it gets the instance of the *directly* enclosing class, then it gets the "top-level" enclosing class from that.

Comment: @m0skit0 yes. May be he was the sole to understand my english.

Answer (score 1):

If the inner classes are not 'static', they contain references internally to the class in which they are contained.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you make an inner class static, then yes, it does have a reference to the instance it exists within, and can reference it members (including private), the same goes for inner inner classes, inner inner inner classes and so on.

Comment: I think the question is about **how** is this done internally.

Answer (score 0):

public and private is a pointer issue, it's a compiler issue.

The question is one of the compiler **enforcing** the scope of a class/variable/method. 
Because the private method `getEnclosing()` falls with the the scope of `InnerClass`, it can be accessed throughout that class.

Note that pointers have nothing to do with the issue.
Using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) you can still access private members of a class.

Comment: I think he means the opposite: how `InnerClass` can access `EnclosingClass`.

Comment: @m0skit0, yes, because innerinner is a part of inner, it can access anything around it, that makes sense.